# OpenCV Unresolved External Symbols - Other Libraries Needed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, linker

I'm trying to use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) 2.3.1 for a video capture and processing app. I downloaded the precompiled libraries from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3.1/) and went to compile a test application using the static libraries found in the `build\x86\vc10\staticlib` of the download folder. Upon trying to compile, Visual Studio greets me with the linker errors shown below. Having worked with libpng, gzip, and a few others in the past, I recognize the functions from those libraries in the linker errors.

Does using the precompiled libraries of OpenCV also require me to link in libpng, libjpeg, gzip, and numerous others, or am I missing something?

```
1>opencv_core231d.lib(persistence.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gzputs referenced in function "void __cdecl icvPuts(struct CvFileStorage *,char const *)" (?icvPuts@@YAXPAUCvFileStorage@@PBD@Z)
1>opencv_core231d.lib(persistence.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gzclose referenced in function "void __cdecl icvClose(struct CvFileStorage *)" (?icvClose@@YAXPAUCvFileStorage@@@Z)
1>opencv_core231d.lib(persistence.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gzopen referenced in function _cvOpenFileStorage
1>opencv_core231d.lib(persistence.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gzgets referenced in function "char * __cdecl icvGets(struct CvFileStorage *,char *,int)" (?icvGets@@YAPADPAUCvFileStorage@@PADH@Z)
1>opencv_core231d.lib(persistence.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gzrewind referenced in function "void __cdecl icvRewind(struct CvFileStorage *)" (?icvRewind@@YAXPAUCvFileStorage@@@Z)
1>opencv_core231d.lib(persistence.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gzeof referenced in function "int __cdecl icvEof(struct CvFileStorage *)" (?icvEof@@YAHPAUCvFileStorage@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(window_w32.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateToolbarEx@52 referenced in function "int __cdecl icvCreateTrackbar(char const *,char const *,int *,int,void (__cdecl*)(int),void (__cdecl*)(int,void *),void *)" (?icvCreateTrackbar@@YAHPBD0PAHHP6AXH@ZP6AXHPAX@Z3@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIFileRelease@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CvCaptureAVI_VFW::close(void)" (?close@CvCaptureAVI_VFW@@UAEXXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIStreamRelease@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CvCaptureAVI_VFW::close(void)" (?close@CvCaptureAVI_VFW@@UAEXXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIStreamGetFrameClose@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall CvCaptureAVI_VFW::close(void)" (?close@CvCaptureAVI_VFW@@UAEXXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIStreamGetFrameOpen@8 referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall CvCaptureAVI_VFW::open(char const *)" (?open@CvCaptureAVI_VFW@@UAE_NPBD@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIStreamInfoA@12 referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall CvCaptureAVI_VFW::open(char const *)" (?open@CvCaptureAVI_VFW@@UAE_NPBD@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIFileGetStream@16 referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall CvCaptureAVI_VFW::open(char const *)" (?open@CvCaptureAVI_VFW@@UAE_NPBD@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIFileOpenA@16 referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall CvCaptureAVI_VFW::open(char const *)" (?open@CvCaptureAVI_VFW@@UAE_NPBD@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIFileInit@0 referenced in function "void __cdecl icvInitCapture_VFW(void)" (?icvInitCapture_VFW@@YAXXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIStreamGetFrame@8 referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall CvCaptureAVI_VFW::grabFrame(void)" (?grabFrame@CvCaptureAVI_VFW@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ICClose@4 referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall CvCaptureCAM_VFW::closeHIC(void)" (?closeHIC@CvCaptureCAM_VFW@@IAEXXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ICSendMessage@16 referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall CvCaptureCAM_VFW::closeHIC(void)" (?closeHIC@CvCaptureCAM_VFW@@IAEXXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _capCreateCaptureWindowA@32 referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall CvCaptureCAM_VFW::open(int)" (?open@CvCaptureCAM_VFW@@UAE_NH@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _capGetDriverDescriptionA@20 referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall CvCaptureCAM_VFW::open(int)" (?open@CvCaptureCAM_VFW@@UAE_NH@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ICDecompress referenced in function "public: virtual struct _IplImage * __thiscall CvCaptureCAM_VFW::retrieveFrame(int)" (?retrieveFrame@CvCaptureCAM_VFW@@UAEPAU_IplImage@@H@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ICOpen@12 referenced in function "public: virtual struct _IplImage * __thiscall CvCaptureCAM_VFW::retrieveFrame(int)" (?retrieveFrame@CvCaptureCAM_VFW@@UAEPAU_IplImage@@H@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIStreamSetFormat@16 referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall CvVideoWriter_VFW::createStreams(struct CvSize,bool)" (?createStreams@CvVideoWriter_VFW@@IAE_NUCvSize@@_N@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIMakeCompressedStream@16 referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall CvVideoWriter_VFW::createStreams(struct CvSize,bool)" (?createStreams@CvVideoWriter_VFW@@IAE_NUCvSize@@_N@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVISaveOptions@20 referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall CvVideoWriter_VFW::createStreams(struct CvSize,bool)" (?createStreams@CvVideoWriter_VFW@@IAE_NUCvSize@@_N@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIFileCreateStreamA@12 referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall CvVideoWriter_VFW::createStreams(struct CvSize,bool)" (?createStreams@CvVideoWriter_VFW@@IAE_NUCvSize@@_N@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(cap_vfw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AVIStreamWrite@32 referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall CvVideoWriter_VFW::writeFrame(struct _IplImage const *)" (?writeFrame@CvVideoWriter_VFW@@UAE_NPBU_IplImage@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_image_destroy referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::close(void)" (?close@Jpeg2KDecoder@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_stream_close referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::close(void)" (?close@Jpeg2KDecoder@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_image_decode referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@Jpeg2KDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_stream_fopen referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@Jpeg2KDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_matrix_destroy referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@Jpeg2KDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_image_readcmpt referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@Jpeg2KDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_matrix_create referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@Jpeg2KDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_image_getcmptbytype referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@Jpeg2KDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_cmprof_destroy referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@Jpeg2KDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_image_chclrspc referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@Jpeg2KDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_cmprof_createfromclrspc referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@Jpeg2KDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_image_encode referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@Jpeg2KEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_image_strtofmt referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@Jpeg2KEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_image_create referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@Jpeg2KEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_image_writecmpt referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent8u(void *,class cv::Mat const &)" (?writeComponent8u@Jpeg2KEncoder@cv@@IAE_NPAXABVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_init referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::JasperInitializer::JasperInitializer(void)" (??0JasperInitializer@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg2000.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jas_cleanup referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::JasperInitializer::~JasperInitializer(void)" (??1JasperInitializer@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_destroy_read_struct referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::close(void)" (?close@PngDecoder@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_error referenced in function "protected: static void __cdecl cv::PngDecoder::readDataFromBuf(void *,unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (?readDataFromBuf@PngDecoder@cv@@KAXPAXPAEI@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_get_io_ptr referenced in function "protected: static void __cdecl cv::PngDecoder::readDataFromBuf(void *,unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (?readDataFromBuf@PngDecoder@cv@@KAXPAXPAEI@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_get_IHDR referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_read_info referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_init_io referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_read_fn referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_longjmp_fn referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_create_info_struct referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_create_read_struct referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_read_end referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_read_image referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_read_update_info referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_rgb_to_gray referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_gray_to_rgb referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_bgr referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8 referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_palette_to_rgb referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_strip_alpha referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_swap referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_strip_16 referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@PngDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_destroy_write_struct referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@PngEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_write_end referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@PngEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_write_image referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@PngEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_write_info referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@PngEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_IHDR referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@PngEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_compression_strategy referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@PngEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_compression_level referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@PngEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_filter referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@PngEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_compression_mem_level referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@PngEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_write_fn referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@PngEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_create_write_struct referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::PngEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@PngEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFSetWarningHandler referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::TiffDecoder::TiffDecoder(void)" (??0TiffDecoder@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFSetErrorHandler referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::TiffDecoder::TiffDecoder(void)" (??0TiffDecoder@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFClose referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::TiffDecoder::close(void)" (?close@TiffDecoder@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFGetField referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::TiffDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@TiffDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFOpen referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::TiffDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@TiffDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFReadEncodedTile referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::TiffDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@TiffDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFReadEncodedStrip referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::TiffDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@TiffDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFReadRGBATile referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::TiffDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@TiffDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFReadRGBAStrip referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::TiffDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@TiffDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFRGBAImageOK referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::TiffDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@TiffDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFIsTiled referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::TiffDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@TiffDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFWriteScanline referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall cv::TiffEncoder::writeLibTiff(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?writeLibTiff@TiffEncoder@cv@@IAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFScanlineSize referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall cv::TiffEncoder::writeLibTiff(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?writeLibTiff@TiffEncoder@cv@@IAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_tiff.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TIFFSetField referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall cv::TiffEncoder::writeLibTiff(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?writeLibTiff@TiffEncoder@cv@@IAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_resync_to_restart referenced in function "void __cdecl cv::jpeg_buffer_src(struct jpeg_decompress_struct *,struct cv::JpegSource *)" (?jpeg_buffer_src@cv@@YAXPAUjpeg_decompress_struct@@PAUJpegSource@1@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_destroy_decompress referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::JpegDecoder::close(void)" (?close@JpegDecoder@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_read_header referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@JpegDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_stdio_src referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@JpegDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_CreateDecompress referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@JpegDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_std_error referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegDecoder::readHeader(void)" (?readHeader@JpegDecoder@cv@@UAE_NXZ)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_finish_decompress referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@JpegDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_read_scanlines referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@JpegDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_start_decompress referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegDecoder::readData(class cv::Mat &)" (?readData@JpegDecoder@cv@@UAE_NAAVMat@2@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_alloc_huff_table referenced in function "int __cdecl cv::my_jpeg_load_dht(struct jpeg_decompress_struct *,unsigned char *,struct JHUFF_TBL * * const,struct JHUFF_TBL * * const)" (?my_jpeg_load_dht@cv@@YAHPAUjpeg_decompress_struct@@PAEQAPAUJHUFF_TBL@@2@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_destroy_compress referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@JpegEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_finish_compress referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@JpegEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_write_scanlines referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@JpegEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_start_compress referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@JpegEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_set_quality referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@JpegEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_set_defaults referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@JpegEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_stdio_dest referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@JpegEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>opencv_highgui231d.lib(grfmt_jpeg.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_CreateCompress referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::JpegEncoder::write(class cv::Mat const &,class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (?write@JpegEncoder@cv@@UAE_NABVMat@2@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>D:\work\SimCapture\OpenCVTest\Debug\OpenCVTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 108 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several missing static libs in OpenCV 2.3.1 Windows package. These libraries are usually built as part of OpenCV library and you don't need to install them separately. So you can build OpenCV from sources yourself or use dynamic libraries from the package.

Comment: So my only options are to re-build the source myself or use use the dynamic libraries? There's no way I can use the pre-built static libraries without hunting down the dependencies?

Answer (score 18):

I have a static build of OpenCV with most of the bells and whistles. VC10 OpenCV2.4.9(OCL woo) To fix a very similar problem I just linked to all of the following:

```
libpng.lib
libtiff.lib
zlib.lib
IlmImf.lib
libjasper.lib
libjpeg.lib
```

They were inside C:\Lib\opencv249\opencv\bld32\3rdparty\lib\Release

-Not sure which one did it but what the heck. Thanks Loozie!

PK

Comment: thx. that solves the linker issues. i found the libs in my distrib (2.4.8) also in the staticlib folder (build/x86/v12/staticlib)

Comment: `$(SolutionDir)opencv-build\3rdparty\lib\Debug`

Answer (score 11):

symbol _*imp*_CreateToolbarEx@52 referenced in function "int __cdecl icvCreateTrackbar(char const *,char const *,int *,int,void (__cdecl*)(int),void (__cdecl*)(int,void *),void *)" (?icvCreateTrackbar@@YAHPBD0PAHHP6AXH@ZP6AXHPAX@Z3@Z)

add comctl32.lib to your linker input.

but after adding all this I still have lots of link errors don't know why...

like

higui.lib(window_w32.obj), _imp_getDCOrfEx@8

higui.lib(window_w32.obj), _imp_getClipBox@8

***problem solved.***

just add Gdi32.lib and my project goes fine.

to conclude:

1.build your own static lib with cmake.

2.3rd party libs should be added too.

3.windows libs like comctl32.lib, gdi32.lib should be added too.

4.careful check whether the libs(3rd) is complied /MTd mood. I have see LIBCMT.lib and MSVCRT.lib problems.

good luck.

Answer (score 8):

Piecing together several of the other answers that I needed to get this to work, I needed to include this complete list in Linker >> Input >> Additional Dependencies:

```
opencv_core248d.lib
opencv_imgproc248d.lib
opencv_highgui248d.lib
opencv_ml248d.lib
opencv_video248d.lib
opencv_features2d248d.lib
opencv_calib3d248d.lib
opencv_objdetect248d.lib
opencv_contrib248d.lib
opencv_legacy248d.lib
opencv_flann248d.lib
libpngd.lib
libtiffd.lib
zlibd.lib
IlmImfd.lib
libjasperd.lib
libjpegd.lib
comctl32.lib
gdi32.lib
vfw32.lib
```

after ensuring that the project's Runtime Library is set to the /MTd option.

This is for Visual Studio 2013

Comment: This brings the end of a 4 hours struggle, Thank you sir !

Answer (score 5):

the _avi* ones apparently can be found by linking ("additional dependencies") against 
vfw32.lib

Answer (score 3):

For the first 6 errors (_gzputs, etc...), you should to add zlib.lib (or zlibd.lib in Debug configuration) to your linker input.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must use the option "Use MFC in a Static Library" to make it work with static libraries.

Comment: Why are you talking about MFC?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similiar problem with latest opencv built with Vs 2015 x64,

but after I added these third party libraries( at 3rd party/library/Debug or Release) , the problem was solved.

```
IlmImfd.lib
libjasperd.lib
libjpegd.lib
libpngd.lib
libtiffd.lib
libwebpd.lib
zlibd.lib
```