# Windows has triggered a breakpoint opencv vs2010

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

The code at the bottom gives the result:

[image: result]

When a key is pressed, an error message is displayed:

[image: error]

How can I fix this? Tested on VS2010 Win8 and WinXp with using MFC as a static library.
EDIT1: in both cases the target platform is Win32
EDIT2: the problem disappears on Win8 when the use of MFC is switched to "use standard windows  libraries". On WinXp it gives an access violation and points to free.c: retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);
EDIT3: Opencv 2.4.7 is used

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int mindistance = 50; // minimum distance between 2 circle centres       
int hi = 255, lo = 20; //the maximum and minimum radius of the circles


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

Mat orig = imread(argv[1]);
Mat display = orig.clone();
Mat snooker, edges;
cvtColor(orig, snooker, CV_RGB2GRAY);
Canny(snooker, edges, 20, 50, 3);
vector<Vec3f> circles;

HoughCircles(edges, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, mindistance, hi, lo);

for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ ) 
{

    Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
    int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    if (radius < (min(snooker.rows, snooker.cols)/10) ) 
        continue;

    // draw the green circle center
    circle( display, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );

    // draw the blue circle outline
    circle( display, center, radius, Scalar(255,0,0), 3, 8, 0 );

}

imshow( "circles", display );
imshow("snooker", snooker);
imshow("edges", edges);
waitKey();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: that particular image host must not be allowed on SO.

Answer (score 0):

similar to [OpenCV Unresolved External Symbols - Other Libraries Needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098272/opencv-unresolved-external-symbols-other-libraries-needed#new-answer?newreg=210d34053daa48ff95e824a83f82340b)

since you use MFC as a static library,you should add .lib in the /staticlib instead of /lib

for example "opencv\build\x86\vc10\staticlib"

and add following additional .lib

```
(in /staticlib but not in /lib,example for debug version as 'd' before '.lib')
libpngd.lib
libtiffd.lib
zlibd.lib
IlmImfd.lib
libjasperd.lib
libjpegd.lib

(part of mfc i thought)
comctl32.lib
gdi32.lib
vfw32.lib
```

according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21946953/3800477